# Does reperforming failed IO operations achieve anything?

Tags: c++, windows, io, disk

A common pattern I've encountered in my office is if we fail an IO operation, we wait a short amount of time and try again a couple of times in the hope it suddenly starts working.

Example of what I'm talking about:

```
bool WriteAFile()
{
    uint32_t writeAttempts = 0;
    do
    {
        if (WriteFile(/*...*/))
        {
            break;
        }
        Sleep(50);
        writeAttempts++;
    } while (writeAttempts < 3);
    return writeAttempts < 3;
}
```

I imagine this behaviour originally popped up to prevent failures when working with files which are locked by another process temporarily... which makes a some sense... however, I fail to see how this is applicable to other operations.

Does repeating IO operations in this fashion increase your chances of writing 'good' data to the disk? Can it be used as a workaround for dying drives? Are there any other legitimate uses for this kind of behaviour?

PS: While I've marked this as a C++ Windows example, I'm interested to hear if there are any compelling reasons to do this with other languages/platforms as well!

Comment: I suspect this question will be closed as too subjective.  But IMO, no, unless you have a specific reason why a particular operation should be retried, you shouldn't do so.

Comment: I also agree that it's a bad idea unless you have a _really_ good reason.  Imagine the "disk sponge" that just sits there, waiting for more disk to free up, only to wake up and eat it...

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I've renamed the title of the question for clarity.

Comment: Missing in your example: a **timeout**. Retrying is a common pattern at all levels of i/o. And it often works. It's there in the lowest levels drivers, and at the highest level it's about the most common solution employed by a human operator. For example, when sending a mail fails, just send it again (my mother has to do that all the time, for reasons unknown, but apparently network-related).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The example contains a timeout (`Sleep(50)`)

Comment: @EdS.: no, a timeout is a limit on the total time spent on a achieving a goal. most every timeout loop includes a delay. this loop has the delay but not the timeout, instead using a max number of retries.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I guess it depends.  Writing a file to a local store?  I would be very surprised to see an overall timeout because, well... that would make no sense.  Network communication? Sure, you're not going to wait forever for a response.  But yeah, I shouldn't have said "timeout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as usual...

## It Depends

Offhand, there are a few reasons why this might be valid/desirable:

- you're writing to a removable drive that may not be instantly ready
- you're writing to a network drive that might disappear and reappear a few milliseconds later (temporary network glitch)
- something complete different...

One thing is almost certain: that kind of retry mechanism was not coded accidentally or casually!

I suggest tracking down the original author and asking him/her why he/she did that... there might be a very good reason, or the original reason might be long obsoleted.